# ADF Essentials in Glassfish: AUTOSUBMIT and VALUECHANGELISTENER attribute makes a message appear in the Web Browser

Tags: glassfish, weblogic, oracle-adf, page-refresh, browser-refresh

I have a ADF project in Jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0, one of my pages contains this:

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="HEllO" value="#{bean.data}" id="id1" autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{bean.createNewData}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.list}" id="id2"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

I deployed it to **Weblogic** and everything worked fine.

Then I deployed it to **Glassfish** using the **ADF Essential** libraries. And it seems to work fine, but there is a unsuspected behavior at any place where there is a attribute AUTOSUBMIT. Everytime the value of the component containing the **AUTOSUBMIT="true"** is changed I have this behavior...

- **Firefox**: A message saying: "To display this page, Firefox must send
  information that will repeat any acction..."
- **IE**: A message saying: "To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.."
- **Chrome**: It redirects to the back page.
- **Opera**: It redirects to the back page.

**EDIT**: The same happen when I have **PARTIALSUBMIT** set to true. I realized that I have to have the **valueChangeListener**  attribute in order to get message.

Answer (score 1):

Autosubmit=true will make (by default) your page to resubmit entirely. You should use partial triggers to avoid this. Set the ID of this component to the 'partial Triggers' attribute of the component you want to refresh (form,table, etc.). You should set 'partialSubmit=true' to your first component.